# How to get arguments from two lists which makes the value of any function maximum?

Tags: python, list

```
any_func=lambda x,y:x/(y+1)
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2=[4,5,6,7,9,2,3,5,7,8]
```

I have two lists list1 and list2,I want to Step 1:get element pair from the two lists which makes the function any_func has maximum value, and step2: then remove these two elements from original lists, continue step 1 and step 2 until list1 or list2 is empty,summation of all results of any_func.
Is there any trick with python?

Comment: What is an "augment"?

Comment: No, there's no "trick" to implementing an algorithm in Python.

Comment: Are only matching pairs from the lists (in terms of the element positions) allowed, or all combinations?

Comment: I agree with @torazaburo, the title is not very clear, nor very interesting.

Comment: Sorry,There is a typo in my title

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the cartesian product of the 2 lists, `itertools.product()` gives you the cartesian product.
If you want the `max` then the `key` argument to `max()` defines how you evaluate the max:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> max(it.product(list1, list2), key=lambda x: any_func(x[0], x[1]))
(8, 2)
```

However it sounds like you just want the `sum` of this product:

```
>>> sum(any_func(a, b) for a, b in it.product(list1, list2))
61.94285714285714
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this functionality!

Comment: This is what I am looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood well from your question. The trick that I used is to construct a sort of matrix:

```
I = [ list1[ 0] , list1[ 0] , ... , list1[ 0] , list1[ 1] , list1[ 1] , ... ]
J = [ list2[ 0] , list2[ 1] , ... , list2[-1] , list2[ 0] , list2[ 1] , ... ]
```

which is evaluated. The result is stored in one list. The only thing that then remains is to reconstuct the original indices, whereby we use the fact that we know that `list2` is repeated for each item of `list1`.

Here is what I made of it:

```
# some function to evaluate
any_func = lambda x,y : x/(y+1)

# some input data
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [4,5,6,7,9,2,3,5,7,8]
total = 0.

# loop until one of the lists is empty
while len(list1)>0 and len(list2)>0:

  # construct a lists of all combinations of "list1" and "list2", evaluate func.
  list_func = [any_func(i,j) for i in list1 for j in list2]
  # find the index of the maximum and trace back to list-index
  idx_max   = max(enumerate(list_func),key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
  idx_2     = idx_max%len(list2)
  idx_1     = int((idx_max-idx_2)/len(list2))
  # add to the requested summation
  total    += list1[idx_1]+list2[idx_2]
  # take elements for lists
  list1     = list1[:idx_1]+list1[idx_1+1:]
  list2     = list2[:idx_2]+list2[idx_2+1:]

print('list1 = ',list1)
print('list1 = ',list2)
```

P.S. I didn't understand what you meant by ",summation of all results of any_func". Please try to write as clearly as possible.

Comment: Thank you , I want to summation of the results of any_func which is called with arguments from the two lists which makes the function maximum, every time when the fhe function is called with the two arguments, the arguments is removed from original lists.

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: Your posts is what I want, Could you make it more concise.I only want the summation .